# How put all extension of a datatables jquery in the dt-toolbar in spesific order?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I used the datatables jQuery plugin in my tables, and I add a button to the dt-toolbar. I want to add all extension of a datatables plugin like: Show and hide columns, filter, show number of rows in page.

I tried this code :

```
"sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12  '<'toolbar1'f>> <'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 '<'toolbar'lC>>>"
```

In the toolbar I add my button with this code:

```
$("div.toolbar").prepend('<button class=" btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" > Ajouter fonction</button>');
$("div.toolbar").addClass('text-right');
```

I have this result:

[image]

but I want the filter and show rows on the left, and the button and the show hide column on the right, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]So if I understand you right, you want the two buttons on the right  and the filter and page length control on the left.  I changed it from your button to a custom button and the col visibility button to make sure the had the same look and feel.

http://live.datatables.net/huwoyete/3/edit

I added the classes:

```
.movel {float:left}
.mover{float:right}
```

then the code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {


    var table = $('#example').DataTable({

    dom: "<'movel'f><'movel'l><'mover'B>ti",
    buttons:[{"text":"Ajouter fonction", action:function(){
   // put your action here.

  // I did it this way so the buttons have the same look and feel.

    }}, "colvis" ]
  });

} );
```

Comment: now i want to change the default value of change entries !?? i tried              "sLengthMenu" : [25, 50,75, 100],
 "iDisplayLength": 25    but not working ?

Comment: in the latest version, you just need to add pageLength:25,   I updated the link above to show this.

Answer (score 0):

```
This the answer of the second question !! 

"oLanguage": {

  "sLengthMenu" : "<label>Show <select name='my-table_length' aria-controls='my-table' class='form-control input-sm'> <option value='5'>5</option> <option value='10'>10</option> <option value='25'>25</option> <option value='50'>50</option> </select>entries </label>"


          },
```